# Triggering browser events for testing

Tags: javascript, d3.js, jasmine

I'm trying to write some tests for some custom event handling that I've created in `D3`, but I can't figure out an appropriate way to trigger these events that still works properly with D3's internals.

I won't go into the exact implementation details of the custom eventing, but will give a brief example of what I've got. So firstly there is a function that hooks up a range of events to an SVG element referred to as `g`. For simplicity I'll use the `mousedown` event to explain my problem:

```
var events = function(g) {
    container = g;

    // Register the raw events required
    g.on("mousedown", mousedown)
     .on("mouseenter", mouseenter)
     .on("mouseleave", mouseleave)
     .on("click", clicked)
     .on("contextmenu", contextMenu)
     .on("dblclick", doubleClicked);

    return events;
};
```

When the `mousedown` event fires this will call the following function:

```
function mousedown(d, i) {

    // Record the initial position of the mouse down
    windowStartPosition = getWindowPosition();
    position = getPosition();

    // Do more stuff

    // Trigger a mouse down event
    dispatch.mousedown.call(this, d, i);
}

function getWindowPosition() {
    var point = {
        x: d3.event.clientX,
        y: d3.event.clientY,
        dx: 0,
        dy: 0
    };

    if (position) {
        point.dx = windowPosition.x -point.x;
        point.dy = windowPosition.y - point.y;
    }       

    return point;
};
```

So I wish to test this code using `Jasmine`, I've setup my custom events up on an SVG `circle` and I now want to fire them to test my code. Note that `myfunc` is a `Jasmine` spy.

```
it("triggers mouse down", function () {
    events.on("mousedown", myfunc);
    // Trigger mouse down
    expect(myfunc).toHaveBeenCalled();
})
```

So I've currently tried 2 different ways to trigger this event on a circle, using `D3` to get the event and fire it manually:

```
circle.on("mousedown")();
```

And using jQuery to select and trigger the event:

```
$("circle").trigger("mousedown");
```

Unfortunately what I find is that my `getWindowPosition()` call fails, and this is because `d3.event` is null.

I'm therefore trying to figure out a way to trigger an event that will behave as much like a real click as possible, such that `D3` correctly sets up the d3.event information. Can anyone make any other suggestions on how I might trigger this event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds pretty much like a similar problem I had to fight my way through a couple of weeks ago. Your approach was the first which occured to me at that time. After doing some research I concluded it is not going to work for the following reasons:

The `jQuery` spec tells us about the [`jQuery.trigger()`](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/) method:

> Although `.trigger()` simulates an event activation, complete with a synthesized event object, it does not perfectly replicate a naturally-occurring event.

There are two drawbacks resulting from this behaviour:

1. The `d3.event` will not get populated with the triggered event leaving it `null` as you have already mentioned.
2. Even if you tried to set the `d3.event` programmatically to the *synthesized event* jQuery created you would just stumble into the next problem noticing that it is pretty much blank. Since the event did not result from a real mouse click there won't be any coordinates (like `.clientX`, `.clientY`) in it. Your code would therefore break on this shortcomming.

Eventually, I ended up creating my own [`MouseEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent):

```
// Initialize the event as needed.
var mouseEventInit = {
    "button": 0,
    "clientX": 0,  // maybe something like circle.getBoundingClientRect().left + 1
    "clientY": 0   // maybe something like circle.getBoundingClientRect().top + 1
    // ... fill any properties you need.
};

// create new event and...
var event = new MouseEvent("click", mouseEventInit);
```

If you need to support Internet Explorer you have to use the deprecated method `MouseEvent.initMouseEvent()` since the use of a new event object which was created via the constructor is not yet supported by IE:

```
var event = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
event.initMouseEvent( /* params */ );
```

I used browser detection and switched to the correct way of setting up the event object.

Having created the new event object you are ready to dispatch it to the desired target by using method [`dispatchEvent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent) of interface `EventTarget` which is implemented by DOM's `Element`:

```
// dispatch it to the target
circle.dispatchEvent(event);
```

This way you end up with a fully fledged event which will also be recognized by d3 putting it to `d3.event` accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a scoping issue.  Try calling the d3.event within the mousedown handler and see if the value is still null.  If so, simply move the getWindowPosition function declaration to within the mousedown handler scope.

Comment: Probably should be a comment, but I can confirm that it's null directly within the mousedown handler too.